# undefined method 'keys' when using upsert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I'd like to use the upsert_all method to insert (and update) record from a collection
in a simple query, for example:

```
books = [] 

10.times do |i|
  books << Book.new(name: "book #{i}")
end

Book.upsert_all(books)
```

however, I get the following error:

```
.../activemodel-6.1.4.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:469:in `method_missing': undefined method `keys' for #<Book id: nil, name: "book 0"> (NoMethodError)
```

And what I am looking for is to be able to make an insert all or upsert_all of an arbitrary collection as an books for example, if you could help me I would be grateful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`upsert_all` expect an array of hashes, not ActiveRecord objects:

```
books = [] 

10.times do |i|
  books << { name: "book #{i}" }
end

Book.upsert_all(books)
```

Comment: A more elegant way to write it would be `books = 10.times.map { |i| { name: "book #{i}" }}`.

Comment: You're right, and more elegant and follow the good practices to assign in each collection.  Thank you very much @max :D

Comment: @max - Actually, it should be `Array.new(10) { |i| {name: "book #{i}"} }` :)